# Showing that $\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}=\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt6}{2}$

Tags: radicals, nested-radicals

So I was playing around on the calculator, and it turns out that $$\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}=\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt6}{2}$$
Does anyone know a process to derive this?

Comment: Have you tried squaring both sides? It gives what you want.

Comment: One can denest radicals by following the form of a perfect square trinomial.

Comment: You can read this paper which is often cited as reference for automatisation of the denesting process http://www.cybertester.com/data/denest.pdf

Comment: No need for fancy 'denesting' here though!

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt6}{2}=\frac{1+\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}$$ and $$2+\sqrt3=\frac{3+2\sqrt3+1}2$$

Answer (score 5):

$$\sqrt{2+\sqrt3}=\sqrt{\frac{4+2\sqrt3}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{3+2\sqrt3.1+1}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{(\sqrt3+1)^2}{2}}=\frac{\sqrt3+1}{\sqrt{2}} =\frac{\sqrt6+\sqrt{2}}{2}$$

Comment: second to third, there is a mistake. +1 ;)

Comment: @Gon you are right ;);

Answer (score 4):

Both sides are clearly positive, and squaring the left hand side shows that
$$\begin{align}  \left(\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{2}\right)^2&=\frac{\sqrt{2}^2+2\sqrt{2}\sqrt{6}+\sqrt{6}^2}{2^2}\\&=\frac{2+4\sqrt{3}+6}{4}\\&=2+\sqrt{3}.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

To simplify a square root
$$\sqrt{x+\sqrt y}$$
to the form $\sqrt a+\sqrt b$, you are looking for $a$ and $b$ with
$$a+b+2\sqrt{ab}=x+\sqrt y.$$
If $x$ and $y$ are rational, and $a$ and $b$ should be rational (and $y$ isn't the square of a rational), you want
$$a+b=x,\qquad 4ab=y.$$
You can solve for $a$ and $b$ as the roots of the quadratic
$$t^2-tx+\frac y4.$$
In this particular case, the quadratic $t^2-2t+\frac 32$ has two rational roots, and so you can find the square root in this form.

Comment: We may also render explicitly $a=\sqrt{\frac12(x+\sqrt D)},b=\sqrt{\frac12(x-\sqrt D)}$ where these are rational iff $D=x^2-y$ is a perfect square. In this case $x=2, D=1$ immediately leads to $\sqrt{3/2}+\sqrt{1/2}$.

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest way is to square both sides and then compare them.

Formally, consider $\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{2}\right)^{2}=\left(\frac{8+2\sqrt{12}}{4}\right)=2+\sqrt{3}$.
Taking square-root on both sides yields $\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{2}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{3}}$.